# Should I make different layout (xml files) for different android mobiles

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

Should I create different layout folders to store my xml layout files. To support my application over different screen sizes?

I developed an application and when adding drawables it automatically creates different sizes like xdpi ldpi and more but layouts xml file are not auto created to support different screen sizes. should I do it? and also i will edit manifest file to support different sizes by using support-screen tag. and is this all?? And will it also support my landscape or portrait mode.  Please confirm me. I am new to stack and android development.

Edit:
I believe different layout files in different folders.. will just be a copy of each other with only folder name change ad shown in code

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

This is my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context="com.example.root.meeransunday.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="Send Mobile"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/sms"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:onClick="message"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="QR Code"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/qr"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="scan"
        />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="        My Account Balance"
    android:textColor="#0D47A1"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text="PKR 1527.87"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/money"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"
            android:resizeable="true"/>
```

but it does not work on 4 inch screen.

Comment: Please check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: did you check `PercentRelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the layout is the same, there's no need to create multiple layout files, you should use different dimens files to adjust the size of your elements.

If you want your application to look different on a hdpi device than it looks on a xxxhdpi or if you have a mobile and a tablet version of the screen, then you should use multiple layout files.

Comment: I have a5 inch SCREEN OF RIVO PHANTOM PZ15 (DEVELOPMENT MOBILE) AND SAMSUNG GALAXY J1 OF 4INCH SCREEN(TESTING SCREEN) MY APPLICATION IS NOT FIT TO SCREEN IN 4 INCH SCREEN .. WHAT TO DO?

Comment: Screen size and screen density are different things. Probably use different dimens files and make your views smaller for the smaller devices is a good approach. Or if you want to remove elements from you layout so that it fits, use different layout files.

Comment: So @adrian Coman can you please pass the link to study about different Dimens making in android. ??

Comment: There are already multiple links in the comments or answers to this question that can help you. Start with this and continue with the lessons at the bottom: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Answer (score 4):

This should be helpful : https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Anyway I think that you should use max 2 layouts xmls (1 for horizontal view, 1 for vertical view) for activity.

Comment: here it's what I said :) https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: what should be different in both xmls??  like what android tag to us for changing orientations??  and will this also support all screen sizes? like 4 ich and 5 inch..  As currently it is not

Answer (score 2):

Actually creating different xml layouts for different android devices it's depends on requirement. It's always good to have only one xml layout for all type of devices to avoid redundant code, But we can go for creating xml's for all type devices, android has that feature.

Comment: how to make single (one) layout xml file support different  android screen sizes. like 4 inch and 5 inch ?

Comment: You can define only one xml layout that is normal .xml inside your layout directory of android project. By applying proper height and width to each widget of layout you can have single xml.

Comment: See, For these kind of issue better to have separate .xml for small devices. There you can edit your height and width according to small device.

Comment: So @Vinod Pattanshetti I need to create res/layout-large/file.xml and res/layout-small/file.xml and will have to manually test and debug devices for setting height and width? right??

Comment: yes You can use two .xml's one for normal layout's and one for small layout's.

Answer (score 1):

No need to design all the Layouts,If you are making app for Phone as well as Tablets then you can design 2 Layouts. Otherwise design only these
1. Portrait
2. Landscape

Comment: will these 2 layouts layout_portrait.xml and layout_landlscape.xml  be enough to support all screen sizes as well??  like 4 inch and 5 inch screen size??

Comment: Yes, It will support all phones.It will automatically adjust according to Screen size.

Comment: Please see my layout file ( I added)  as an edit @abhishek Kumar it is not working

Comment: Only create one res/layout/my_layout.xml for Portrait & Landscape.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct and rate up. @nimraasad